# regex for matching timestamp

Tags: regex

I need to extract out this text `"start_time":"2018-08-05T17:41:29.933Z"` form this string:

`BLAH text BLAH text "start_time":"2018-08-05T17:41:29.933Z" blah TEXT BLAH text`

I tried this: `\[\"start_time\":\"(.*)\"\]`

But it did not work. What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you matching `[` if there is no `[` in your string?

Comment: `r'\"start_time\":\"(.*?)\"'` ?

Comment: Are you sure you shouldn't instead parse properly your JSON format and get the start time like `var start = parsedJSON.start_time;`? To me, as soon I see people having JSON-alike strings like `foo text bar "prop":"val"` - is clear sign something went really wrong ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This pattern `r'\"start_time\":\"(.*?)\"'` should help you extract date

**Ex:** *in python*

```
import re
s = 'BLAH text BLAH text "start_time":"2018-08-05T17:41:29.933Z" blah TEXT BLAH text'
print(re.findall(r'\"start_time\":\"(.*?)\"', s))
```

**Output:**

```
['2018-08-05T17:41:29.933Z']
```